# Huge margin in the table, how to make it smaller?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here is a page that I have a problem with:
http://musdesigns.com/invoice/guest/view/invoice/3810b25e7b5c22afe2a33a16974732f4

As you can see, the item name field has a huge margin on the right.
Any idea how to fix this?

I would like it to have a small margin similar to the other fields.

Comment: Are you sure there is a margin? At first glance I would say it's a matter of column width.

Comment: You are probably right, it looks like a margin to me since it scales with the text while keeping the white space on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You have to provide specific width for the second "td(column)" or do it for all.
>   If wish to do only for second "td(column)", then you can do like this also.

```
<td style="width: 40%;">Item</td>
```

> or

```
table td:nth-child(2){width:100px;}
```

> or make a class and provide it width and place it on every td

Comment: It will work if I will set the width for every column.
Is there a way to make it scale automaticly, like it is doing now, just without the huge space on the right?

Comment: As you can see, it's scaling automatically till now, but if you provide width in "Pixel" it will get fix only all those column(td) on your table.  
know your needs. for each column you need now much width and make a css and do it. your problem will solve

Answer (score 0):

On your `<th>Item</th>` you can set the width using CSS.

Like:

`<th style="width: 40%;">Item</th>`